# get all page templates

Tags: loop, templates

I am working on a one page WordPress site. It's the first time I have tried this. I am on the fifth version with various degrees of success. I am starting a new version and I deleted everything in the theme folder except the header.php index.php, functions.php, footer.php, page templates and styles.css

When I look in my database in the wp_postmeta, I can see that there are several pages in there that have a template assigned. I have seen this code before so I tried it for the first time to see what I could get. In my index.php file. I have the simple standard loop. you can see that right after the_post() I have tried the get_post_meta. My thought was that it would return all the names of the page templates. But it doesn't I actually get nothing. I tried a var_dump and a foreach loop to see what was in it. I get nada. I don't know why

As a secondary question still related, my query below does not return every post in the database. It is only returning 2 blog posts, ( there are only 2 ) and 8 posts out of a lot. It is not showing any pages that were made. Can you give me a hint as to why?

```
 <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php $template = get_post_meta($post->ID,'_wp_page_template',false); ?>
    <?php var_dump($template); ?>
            <li id="page_<?php the_title(); ?>">


        <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()) {

                }
                the_content('Read the rest of this entry »'); ?>
            </li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php else : ?>

    //Something that happens when a post isn’t found.
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: But `index.php` will display posts, not pages, right? What if you try in `page.php`? Or do a custom query? Search for Template Hierarchy here and in the Codex.

Comment: I checked the template hierarchy. Everything defaults back to the index.php file which is what I want. I guess my confusion came in when "The Loop" didn't supply all posts. There are a lot missing.

Comment: Sorry, Jamie, I missed that part of the Q, my bad...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the `page` post type can have a template assigned (of the default post types), it's the custom template you set in the Page Attributes meta box. If you have a `page.php` template file, your `index.php` will only be used to display `post` post types, so those posts will never have a `_wp_page_template` meta key. As to why you don't get any pages with your `index.php` loop, only the `post` post type gets queried on home and archive pages. If you want to get all posts *and* pages on your home page, use `pre_get_posts` to modify the home page query:

```
function wpa83038_posts_and_pages_on_home( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'page' ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpa83038_posts_and_pages_on_home' );
```

I'm not sure how useful that would be though. Seems you'd want to do another custom query for pages and keep posts separate.

Comment: You had a good idea with the snipppet you posted. I forgot you could do that. I also forgot about the home issue. Thanks for pointing that out. That could be a big part of my issue. including a page, single and category.php is what I am trying now. So far so good.